# cakePHP 3.0 and bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, glyphicons

I want to add glyphicons instead of text in my index, add, edit views.

This works in the index.ctp

```
<?= $this->Html->link(__('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>'), ['action' => 'edit', $user->user_id], array('escape' => false)) ?>
```

But when I do it for the delete action it shows me the glyphicon but it doesn't give me the 'Are you sure you want to delete the user?' anymore

```
<?= $this->Form->postLink(__('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>'), ['action' => 'delete', $user->user_id], array('escape' => false), ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete {0}?', $user->username)]) ?>
```

In the view.ctp it breaks the code that comes after so the content that comes after isn't shown. (in this example that's the content after the glyphicon-pencil. The glyphicon-pencil itself isn't shown as well.

```
<?= $this->Html->link(__('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'), ['action' => 'edit', $user->user_id], ['escape' => false]) ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a closer look at the arguments that you are passing, you are passing 4, where the method only accepts 3, ie the `confirm` option is not passed in the actual options argument.

Proper formatting helps a lot to spot such mistakes.

```
<?=
$this->Form->postLink(
    __('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>'),
    [
        'action' => 'delete',
        $user->user_id
    ],
    [
        'escapeTitle' => false,
        'confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete {0}?', $user->username)
    ]
)
?>
```

And your `FormHelper::link()` example is missing a closing double quote for the `<i>` elements `class` attribute, as well as a closing tag for the element itself:

```
'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>'
```

Also you may want to use `escapeTitle` instead of `escape`, in order to avoid disabling escaping for attributes too.