# CakePHP 3.0 - Post Link - adding classes removes alert confirmation functionality

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

When I add the class array to the postLink, the confirm alert stops working. I have moved the class array into different positions but within the postLink but nothing seems to work.

```
<?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'),
['controller' => '<%= $details['controller'] %>', 'action' => 'delete', <%= $otherPk %>],
['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm'],
['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', <%= $otherPk %>)]) %>
```

The above code will add the right classes to the link, but the confirmation doesn't work, it just deletes the entry right away.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703597/cakephp-3-0-and-bootstrap-glyphicons/29706608#29706608

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `confirm` message and the other html options like `class` go in the same array

```
<?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'),
    ['controller' => '<%= $details['controller'] %>', 'action' => 'delete', <%= $otherPk %>],
    ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm'],'confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', <%= $otherPk %>)]) %>
```

Comment: Thank you! just need to remove the ] after btn-sm'